# allegro animato and deciso in Mazeppa

Tags: piano, classical-music, tempo

In Liszt's 5e étude, Mazeppa, a part has *allegro animato* and then the next one *allegro deciso*.

What are the possibilities and the most likely meaning of those terms ?

I understand that *animato* can mean *more and more animated* or *accelerando over the whole part*, it is a global accelerando, with possibilities of variations inside (eg., like a rubato inside the accelerando)

I understand that *deciso* can mean *decided*, so there should not be hesitation, even though there could be simple deviations inside the part; it also can mean that *allegro deciso* is also a rather fast allegro, with feelings of being unstoppable, absence of doubt, or in other terms, *no ritardendi inside*.

Answer (score 4):

To my understanding, *animato* doesn't mean a progressive change over time, but just means "animated" or "lively." (*Anim**an**do*, as a progressive verb, might have the "getting faster" sense you're thinking of.)* Meanwhile *deciso* (maybe a good English translation is "decisive") might simply color the dramatic interpretation more than anything explicit about tempo; for me, it often means more pronounced articulation.

* If your primary language is French, this could be challenging; as I understand it, this tense is absent in French. So Italian *animato* is equivalent to French *animé*, but *animando* is *plus et plus animé*.